# How to solve Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_segments, x$x0, x$y0, x$x1, x$y1, x$arrow)

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am creating this function by modifying one located in `ggpubr` package, called `show_line_types()`. I want this function to have the number code of the line types:

```
lineas_r <- function () 
{
    lt <- c("1 blank", "2 solid", "3 dashed", "4 dotted", "5 dotdash", 
        "6 longdash", "7 twodash")
    d <- data.frame(lt = factor(lt, levels = lt))
    ggplot() + scale_x_continuous(name = "", limits = c(0, 1), 
        breaks = NULL) + scale_linetype_identity() + geom_segment(data = d, 
        mapping = aes(x = 0, xend = 1, y = lt, yend = lt, linetype = lt)) + 
        labs(y = "") + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", 
        color = "black"))
}
```

Once it is run, I get this error:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_segments, x$x0, x$y0, x$x1, x$y1, x$arrow) : invalid line type: must be length 2, 4, 6 or 8
```

However, when I do the same with the object `lt` modified, as shown here:

```
lt <- c("blank", "solid", "dashed", "dotted", "dotdash", 
        "longdash", "twodash")
```

I do not get this error.

I tried by modifying the `limits` and the `mapping` arguments inside the `ggplot()` function, but unsuccessfully.

How can I get this image to have the number code along with their names printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are mapping the linetype to a vector which does not contain linetypes as expected. This is one possible solution:

```
lt <- c("blank", "solid", "dashed", "dotted", "dotdash", "longdash", "twodash")
lt_names <- c("1 blank", "2 solid", "3 dashed", "4 dotted", "5 dotdash", "6 longdash", "7 twodash")

d <- data.frame(lt, lt_names)

ggplot() + scale_x_continuous(name = "", limits = c(0, 1), breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_linetype_identity() + 
  geom_segment(data = d, mapping = aes(x = 0, xend = 1, y = lt_names, yend = lt_names, linetype = lt)) + 
  labs(y = "") + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"))
```

[image]